# Add a menu to a specific page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress website and I would like to add a menu that only shows up on a specific page. I have my main navigation set up as follows:

```
Home | Team | Leagues | Media | Links
```

And I would like it so that after you go to the media page, there is a sidebar menu that has links to pages like:

```
Media  
-> Images  
-> Videos
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: For this, you can create a template with different menu registered on your theme.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a new template for the page you need (in theme folder). Set the template as newly created under the Page attributes in your page area.

```
/*
Template Name: Dashboard
*/
```

2) Register new menu location in the functions.php.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'new name', 'theme name' ),
    'id'            => 'new id',
    'description'   => __( 'description', 'theme name' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
) );
```

3)Create new menu and assign pages into the new menu  and assign the nav location as new menu location.

4)Go to the newly created page in theme folder and call the newly registered menu location where exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. The easy way would be to create a new file called page-media.php in
   your theme directory. So when you click on media this file will be
   executed. In this file paste all the code that you currently have in
   page.php.
2. Then open functions.php and register a new side bar.

   register_sidebar( array(
           'name'          => __( 'new name', 'theme name' ),
           'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
           'description'   => __( 'description', 'theme name' ),
           'before_widget' => '',
           'after_widget'  => '',
           'before_title'  => '',
           'after_title'   => '',
       ) );
3. then show the sidebar in page-media.php with this code where ever you want.

   dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );